# Why do I keep getting an error in this Java Code?

Tags: java, syntax-error

I'm writing a program that lets the user select a type of currency, then when they enter in the number and click the 'convert button' the conversion is displayed in a text box. But I keep getting an error on line 36 that says 'class or interface expected public void init ()'

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CurrencyConversionApplet implements ActionListener, ItemListener
{

// Variables

     double  dollars, pounds, euros, ruble, price;

     Image   dollarSign;



    Label lblTitle = new Label ("Enter the dollar amount (do not use commas or dollar signs): ");
    Label lblOutput = new Label (" ");
    TextField txtDollar = new TextField(10);
    Button convButton = new Button("Convert");

    CheckboxGroup chkGroup = new CheckboxGroup();
          Checkbox chkPounds = new Checkbox("British Pounds",false,chkGroup);
          Checkbox chkEuro = new Checkbox("Euros",false,chkGroup);
          Checkbox chkRuble = new Checkbox("Russian Ruble",false,chkGroup);
          Checkbox hiddenBox = new Checkbox("",true,chkGroup);
     Image dollarSign;
}

     public void init()

        {


      add(lblTitle);
      add(txtDollar);
      add(convButton);
      add(chkPounds);
      add(chkEuro);
      add(chkRuble);
          chkPounds.addItemListener(this);
          chkEuro.addItemListener(this);
          chkRuble.addItemListener(this);

      dollarSign=getImage(getDocumentBase(), "dollar.jpg");

      setBackground(Color.blue);
      setForeground(Color.yellow);

        convButton.addActionListener(this);

    }

          public void paint(Graphics g) {
          g.drawImage(dollarSign, 0, 28, this);

    }


 public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent choice)
      {

             dollars = Double.parseDouble(txtDollar.getText());
             pounds = dollars * .62
             euros =  dollars * .71
             ruble = dollars * .03


     if(chkPounds.getState())
        price = pounds;

     if(chkEuro.getState())
        price = euros;

     if(chkRuble.getState())
        price = ruble;

    }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {



lblOutput.setText(Double.toString(price));

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have the `init()` method defined outside of class `CurrencyConversionApplet`. Is that what you want?

The error `'class or interface expected public void init ()'` says it all: The compiler expects there either a class or an interface. And `init()` is none of these.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't you delete that '}' ?

```
Image dollarSign;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading it right, you have an extra `}` just before your declaration line for `Init`, closing the class declaration.

```
     Image dollarSign;
} /* <-- */

     public void init()
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that error because the method `public void init()`
 is not inside the class `CurrencyConversionApplet`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the method `init()` needs to be part of `CurrencyConversionApplet` . So, do this instead -

```
 Image dollarSign;
 } // <-  Remove that and place it at the very end of the program.
```

With that corrected, there are other mistakes too -

```
 pounds = dollars * .62
 euros =  dollars * .71
 ruble = dollars * .03
```

All the above statements of `itemStateChanged` method should be ended by a **;**

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you extend the Applet Class. If this is an applet then you should extend the Applet class

Comment: This is not the reason for this error message, but will pop up next when trying to run this as an applet.